# Strange behavior with ggplot, sf package and orthographic projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, geospatial

Cross posting with gis.stackexchange.com: the ggplot package throws errors for some versions of an orthographic projection. For example, this works fine

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

data("World") ## get built-in data from the tmap package
world.sf <- World
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=40"
# Fix polygons so they don't get cut in ortho projection
ortho_world.sf  <- st_cast(world.sf, 'MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_cast('LINESTRING', do_split=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(npts = npts(geometry, by_feature = TRUE)) %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>% st_transform(crs=projection)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=ortho_world.sf)
```

This projection works as well

```
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=70 +lon_0=-181" ## works fine
```

But all of these throw errors

```
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-180" ## throws error
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-149" ## throws error
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=20 +lon_0=-149" ## throws error
```

The error seems to be in sf, since I get similiar problems with plot in base R. What's going on?

Comment: Could you share the error thrown, when thrown, and insert above ( and is +lon_0=-181, a typo?)

Comment: link to cross-post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468455/strange-behavior-with-ggplot-sf-package-and-orthographic-projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that some of the polygons are degenerate after the transformation, with some features only containing a single point. Polygons in `sf` need at least 4 points. You need to count the points using `npts` *after* the transformation and filter out those with less than four points.

For convenience, let's wrap the code in a function to which we need only pass the projection string:

```r
plot_proj <- function(proj) {
  st_cast(world.sf, 'MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_cast('LINESTRING', do_split = TRUE) %>%
  st_transform(crs = proj) %>%
  mutate(npts = npts(geometry, by_feature = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(npts > 3) %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf()
}
```

Now we can do:

```r
plot_proj("+proj=ortho +lat_0=40")
```

[image]

```r
plot_proj("+proj=ortho +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-180")
```

[image]

```r
plot_proj("+proj=ortho +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-149")
```

[image]

```r
plot_proj("+proj=ortho +lat_0=20 +lon_0=-149")
```

[image]

Comment: This is wonderful. I'll acknowledge this if I ever collect all these map hacks as a package!