# ggplot and sf package: broken polygons after projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, geospatial

My standard hack for fixing broken polygons (see [Strange behavior with ggplot, sf package and orthographic projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77298627/strange-behavior-with-ggplot-sf-package-and-orthographic-projection)) after re-projection does NOT seem to work for the Albers Equal-area projection. What am I missing? Cross posting to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469267/ggplot-and-sf-package-broken-polygons-after-projection

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(lwgeom)
library(mapview)

## load background map of the world 
data("World") ## get built-in data from the tmap package
world.sf <- World
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=world.sf, fill="white") ## looks fine

world.sf %>% st_transform("+proj=ortho +lat_0=40") %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(fill="white")## missing polygons

## standard hack for broken polygons
world.sf <- st_cast(world.sf, 'MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_cast('LINESTRING', do_split=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(npts = npts(geometry, by_feature = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(npts > 3) %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON')

world.sf %>% st_transform("+proj=ortho +lat_0=40") %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(fill="white")## looks good


world.sf %>% st_transform(crs="+proj=aea +lon_0=12.65625 +lat_1=32.7988379 +lat_2=50.7766668 +lat_0=41.7877524 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_sf(fill="white") ## broken polygon

## standard hack doesn't work
```